The angle between two lines
I am working my way through a textbook. The gradient of a line (say, 1) is the tan of the angle. This is obvious because the tan of the angle is the opposite (rise) over adjacent (run) side.
If I have two lines with different gradients, then the difference in gradient is one minus the other. I am told that the difference in angle is: arctan: difference of the gradients/1 plus the product of the gradients.
I am at a loss how this is derived.

Do you know a formula for $\tan(a-b)$?

Hint:
$$\tan(a-b)=\dfrac{\tan(a)-\tan(b)}{1+\tan(a)\tan(b)}$$
This difference formula can be found on Wikipedia.
Addendum:  Derivation as requested:
$$\tan(x-y)=\dfrac{\sin(x-y)}{\cos(x-y)}=\dfrac{\sin x\cos y - \cos x\sin y}{\cos x\cos y +\sin x\sin y}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\dfrac{\sin y}{\cos y}}{1+\dfrac{\sin x\sin y}{\cos x\cos y}}$$
$$=\dfrac{\tan x - \tan y}{1+\tan x\tan y}$$

What I am asking is: how is the formula derived? I can draw the triangles. I can see that the difference in angle is related to the change in the Y axis. But I am not seeing how we get this curious formula.

@Anthony The response of J. W. Tanner has answered your question.  That is, his answer provides a wikipedia link to basic trigonometric identities.  Starting from those identities, J. W. Tanner's answer derives the corresponding formula for $~\tan(x - y).~$  All that remains is (if you feel that it is necessary) to look for a derivation of the formulas for $~\sin(x - y)~$ and $~\cos(x - y).$

Thanks for both these answers. I can see they provide the algebra that gets to the trigonometric formula. I was really looking to understand how the difference between two gradients could be so peculiar. Does anyone know of a link that shows this geometrically? If I draw out the triangles, then what I see is that a line perpendicular to one gradient intercepts the other, and the perpendicular distance is the only undefined quantity, being the side opposite to angle x.

@Anthony, maybe this is what you're looking for then

Thanks you, that is exactly it. It is the same diagram I drew, but showing the workings.
